# Laravel Instagram API , pulling specific hashtag from specific user (eg: pulling #smile from @instaguy). Need help on how to do it

Tags: php, api, laravel, instagram, hashtag

has anyone done any project involving *instagram api on Laravel*? I need help on retrieving specific hashtag from specific user.

```
$user = Instagram::getCurrentUser();

$users = $user->getMedia();

foreach($users as $media)
{
    var_dump($media->images);
}
```

This displays every media on that users profile

I know I need to put something in that `foreach` loop but still cant figure out anything

I then tried putting this in the foreach loop

```
$tag = Instagram::getTag('poster');

$media = $tag->getMedia();
```

when I `var_dump` this, it displays all posts from all users with that hashtag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not supported by Instagram itself.

You have to check for the hashtag yourself in the `foreach` Loop.
I guess `$media->getTags()` should give you the list of tags of this user.

Comment: Yeah it lists down every tags of the user, im still out of idea on how to only display the selected tag from the user.

Comment: I was thinking about storing certain photos based on specific hashtag and cache it before retrieving it. take a look here: japborst.net/posts/creating-a-cached-instragram-feed